# Need suggestion for Ruby and Rails coding standards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing my application using Rails. It has 400 or more models and some models contain more than 200 rows just for relationships, so it's too hard handle it. Are there any ways I can handle my application in more proper and easy ways?

Comment: Need more info. What kind of app are you doing? Is it your first? How did you get to have so many models? Probably you need to abstract more, but without details I cannot give an answer

Comment: Agreed - are 400 models really necessary? More detail would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In application that I'm working with, there are about 100 models. Few things that helped us develop it:

- you can create hierarchical directory structure to models. It is obvious when talking about controllers, but for models it's not that straightforward
- you can split models into logical parts by putting chunks of code into modules
- doing above two points sometimes allows you to see some ways to refactor your code. Some modules might become common between models. Some things can be excluded into methods that will dynamically generate common parts of models
- sometimes modules handle unnecessary logic, and that makes harder to understand them -- if your methods contain lots of `case`s or `if`s to handle different types of objects (like admin/normal user) probably you should use polymorphism
- refactor, refactor, refactor ;-)

Wise refactoring takes a lot of time, but if you drop this part of development, project maintenance will become overwhelming. Check out books about Ruby, RoR, refactoring, metaprogramming. Investing time in learning might also bring effects.